# create a xslt 2.0 transformation pipeline with batch file

Tags: xml, batch-file, xslt

I have around 20 xsl scripts which need to be executed in a certain order. They each produce an output document that is the input document for the next stylesheet.

I only know very basic batch scripting`(mkdir, cd, a simple for loop,...). What would be the best way to do this?

So I'm talking about something like this:

1. a batch file creates an xml file A
2. A is used with script S1 to produce B (using Saxon9he.jar)
3. B is used with script S2 to produce C... and so on

Ideally, I would have one batch script that just starts everything (calls the first batch script, then the first xsl script and so on).

Which batch commands can I use for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try smething like this:

```
SET SAXON_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
REM Path to Java (%JAVA_HOME is Windows environment variable)
SET JAVA_BIN_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\bin
"%JAVA_BIN_HOME%\java" -cp "%SAXON_HOME%\saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform A.xml S1.xsl > B.xml
"%JAVA_BIN_HOME%\java" -cp "%SAXON_HOME%\saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform B.xml S2.xsl > C.xml
... and so on until the 20th stylesheet.
```

you have to set `JAVA_HOME` as a Windows environment variable

Comment: Ah okay. And the transformation from document B to C doesnt start until document B is created? How does that work exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://github.com/hamdikarray/xml-processing-engine-dist

```
java -jar xml-processing-engine-dist-1.00.00-jar-with-dependencies.jar -xpeUri main.xpe
```

and ths main.xpe :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<processing 
  xmlns="http://com.sitc.xml.processing.engine.org/config"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <pipe
    source="'file:/input'"
    destination="'file:/output'">
    <xslt uri="'../A.xslt'"/>
    <xslt uri="'../B.xslt'"/>
    <xslt uri="'../C.xslt'"/>
  </pipe>
</processing>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).